# Upgrading from SharePoint 2010 to 2013, deleting content database

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade, delete

Why do we delete the content database of a new Web Application while upgrading from SharePoint 2010 to 2013?

Answer (score 5):

When you create a new web application, the content database associated with it is fresh in the sense that you haven't added any data to it yet. The purpose of upgrading from SP 2010 to SP 2013 is to carry over the content from SP 2010 to SP 2013. So you delete the original content database as you don't need it and attach the content database from SP 2010 to the web application.

Comment: What if we keep the fresh Copy and attach 2010 content database also?

Comment: IMO there should not be any issues as a web application can have more than one content database. The content database from SP 2010 will have its own site collection/collections and you should be able to use them properly.

Comment: ok.suppose I create one more site collection after upgradation.which content database it will use?

Comment: Not sure, will need some testing :-)